# I get the error 'imagettfbbox() Unable to find a CharMap that I can handle' when trying to generate text in PHP 5.6

Tags: php, gd, php-gd

I've been trying to use the following PHP code to generate a imagettfbbox:

```
$font_path = "/var/www/lib/fonts/Arial.ttf";

$rect = imagettfbbox(10,0,$font_path,"Hello world!");
```

However each time I try I get the following error:

```
Warning (2): imagettfbbox() [function.imagettfbbox]: Unable to find a CharMap that I can handle
```

I have both FreeType and GD support as confirmed with phpinfo(). I can't find any documentation indicating what might be causing this problem and this code works fine on an earlier version of PHP. Am I missing something else?

Comment: you sure that's the correct path for the font file, and it's readable by the process uid?

Comment: @MarcB - To be sure I've changed the .ttf file permissions to 777 and double checked the file path, it's correct.

Comment: I've found the issue - for some reason the file was being corrupted when uploading to my server. I replaced the TTF file with another version and it worked fine! Thanks for your suggestions anyway @MarcB